# SQL GROUP BY where partitions meet condition

Tags: sql

Consider following table:

```
id     var_a     var_b
----------------------
0      abcd      123
1      abcd      245
2      efgh      123
3      abcd      456
4      efgh      211
5      ijkl      123
6      ijkl      456
```

I want to group by var_a in such a way, that each group would have in it var_b = '123' and var_b = '456'. That is, I want to obtain "abcd" and "ijkl" in the set of results. How do I do that?

Comment: Please, could you put your expected output in a table format, like the table you post? What have you tried so far? Please share your code in order to better help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the table and `group by var_a`:

```
select var_a
from tablename
where var_b in ('123', '456')
group by var_a
having count(distinct var_b) = 2
```

The condition in the `having` clause makes sure that both `'123'` and `'456'` exist for the same `var_a`.

Comment: Probably `>=2` in this case, no? `abcd` has a third `var_b` value.

Comment: @EricBrandt the condition is `where var_b in ('123', '456')` so the distinct values of car_b must be exactly 2.

Comment: Sorry. Got it now. I misread the requirement in the question.